# Variable in vue v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs, v-model

I am using a textarea field in a form and if I insert a value from the database into it (using laravel 10 and inertia) it is not displayed.
However, it is displayed in any other place.
It is obvious that the value conflicts with in the v-model

```
<script setup>
...
let form = reactive({
  header: '',
});  
...
</script>

<template>
...
<textarea
v-model="form.header"                                
@input="onInputheader"                              
>{{ article.header }}</textarea>
...
</template>
```

At the same time, I cannot set the default value in the vmodel like this

```
<script>
 data() {
    return {
      form.header: article.header,
}
```

The syntax of form.header is incorrect, and article.header is not defined.

```
</script>.
let form = reactive({
  header: article.header,
});
```

article.header is not defined too

How could I pass the value of the variable to the texarea with v-model field

Comment: Why in the second block of code do you write it as `return { form.header: article.header,`, It have to be `return { form: { header: article.header } ...`

Comment: Good idea but "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: article is not defined" . I have ...defineProps({
  article: String,
});... Maybe I can get variable into script. Article generating in backend     public function edit(string $url)
    {
        Article::find($url);
        return Inertia::render('Articles/Edit', [
            'article' => Article::where('url', '=', $url)->first(),
        ],  
    );

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `{{ article.header }}` from inside of textarea tag because mustache syntax inside textarea tag wont work. Docs:https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#multiline-text and also make changes suggested by @Joyful in the comments.

```
<script setup>
...
let form = reactive({
  header: '',
});  
...
</script>

<template>
...
<textarea
v-model="form.header"                                
@input="onInputheader"                              
></textarea>
...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Need to declare variable to use it in script

```
let props = defineProps({
  article: String,
});

let form = reactive({
  header: props.article.header,
});
```